# How can I patch a leak in my sprinkler system manifold?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I found a couple tiny leaks in my sprinkler system manifold (see red circles in picture); While I already plan to have the manifold replaced, is there some way I can temporarily patch the leaks?

[image]

Comment: To answer your specific question: not easily.  To fix that you replace the fitting, which is a transition from threaded adapter to SLIP.  In this case you’ll need to add another coupling and short piece of pipe to take up space you’ll create by cutting out the old.  If it’s to be replaced, hasten that repair and make it happen, it’s the same process.

Comment: @Tyson - Are there no putties or caulks I can put over the leak to seal it temporarily?

Comment: @Tyson I have a similar issue in a piece I'm not sure what it is... it may be the pressure regulator.  But in my case the whole system is old and needs to be replaced, which I'm not able to do yet - but it's also difficult to replace this part of the system piecemeal due to space constraints (as in, without tearing up a bunch of unrelated stuff like sidewalk just to be able to get enough space to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are epoxy-based putties designed for leaks like this, but your sprinklers might work at a pressure higher than the putty can handle.  JBWeld makes one which is sold in home improvement stores.

If you try it, be sure to leave the water off while the putty dries, and use enough to circle the entire leaky joint.

Wear gloves to mix and apply.  Don't expect to be able to remove the putty from anything it is attached to - when you replace the manifold you'll need to replace the puttied parts too.

Comment: how do you apply the putty?  Do you just apply to the outside area where the leaking is occurring? Or do you need some kind of join on the outside to hold it on?  If so, what?